# Splitting up students into groups

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Mr. Porter has 12 students in his combinatorics class. In the first week of class, he
tells his students to break up into 4 groups of 3 people each to work on a project.
In the second week, he assigns another project, and he tells his students to break
up into 6 groups of 2 people each, such that none of the people in each group were
in the same group in the first week. In how many ways can the students form the
groups in the second week? (Assume that the order in which they form the groups
does not matter.)

(A) 1296 (B) 2546 (C) 2995 (D) 3348 (E) 10395

First, I pick some random person named Joe. Then, he has 9 choices for who he can be paired up with. This step eliminates B and C. Now we pick another person from Joe's group. He has 8 people to choose from, but we need to divide by 2 for overcounting to get $9\cdot 8/2=36$. The final person has $7$ ways. But, none of the answers are multiples of $\text{lcm}(36,7)=252$.

Help?

Comment: Although there are indeed $8$ possible partners for the second pairing, whether or not this person was in the same group as Joe's partner will affect pairings down the line.

Comment: There are only three non-isomorphic graphs on $4$ vertices without loops but possibly with parallel edges.  Each vertex of such a graph $G$ represents a group of three from the first week.  Each edge denotes a pair having one member from each group represented by each endpoints of the edge.  If I am not mistaken, the answer is $$3\cdot (3!)^2+3!\cdot 3^2\cdot (3\cdot 2)^2+3!\cdot 3^3\cdot 2!\cdot 2^2=108+1944+1296=3348.$$

Comment: I forgot to say that each graph in my comment above is supposed to be $3$-regular, that is, every vertex has degree $3$.  That is, there are only three $3$-regular loopless multigraphs on $4$ vertices $\{a,b,c,d\}$.  Up to isomorphism, these are all the possible edge multisets: (1) $\big\{\{a,b\},\{a,b\},\{a,b\},\{c,d\},\{c,d\},\{c,d\}\big\}$, (2) $\big\{\{a,b\},\{a,b\},\{a,d\},\{b,c\},\{c,d\},\{c,d\}\big\}$, (3) the complete graph $K_4$.

Comment: The solution by @WETutorialSchool is a bit too advanced for me -- I will need some more time to digest it.  But Joe can be with any of the other $11$ people during second week, and so shouldn't the answer be divisible by $11$?  Only $10395$ is divisible by $11$.

Comment: @antkam Joe can't be with anyone in his original group of $3$, so there are $9$ choices for his partner in the second week. [The "how many ways" is conditioned on the result of the first week.]

Comment: @angryavian - oh, my bad - I thought the OP question was how many ways to form groups for _both_ weeks, in which case the number is a multiple of $11$.  But the OP question was instead how many ways to form groups for _second_ week.  My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WE Tutorial School's approach of looking at graphs with parallel edges is pretty neat and simple. Here is a more painstaking way that involves tons of casework, but has the virtue of completing OP's attempt.

---

Let Joe's original group of 3 be Joe, Alice, and Bob.

There are $9$ choices for Joe's new partner.

Alice has $8$ choices for her partner. There are two cases to consider.

- Case 1. Alice's partner was in the same group of 3 as Joe's partner. ($2$ possibilities)
- Case 2. Alice's partner was not in the same group of $3$ as Joe's partner. ($6$ possibilities)

We take each case separately.

---

Case 1: Bob now has $7$ choices.

One person is in the same group as Joe's partner and Alice's partner. If he chooses that person, then we just need to form pairs out of the remaining two untouched groups of $3$; there are $6$ ways to do that.

Otherwise, Bob chooses one of the $6$ people in the two untouched groups of $3$. Now there remains an untouched group of $3$, another group with $2$ people left, and another group with $1$ person left. There are $6$ ways to pair them up, since each pair must contain one person from the untouched group of $3$.

---

Case 2: Bob also has $7$ choices in this case. There is one untouched group of $3$, and two groups of two people each.

If Bob chooses someone from a group of $2$ ($4$ ways to do this), then there are again $6$ ways to pair up the remaining $6$ people.

If Bob chooses someone from the group of $3$ ($3$ ways to do this), then there are three groups of $2$ left. There are $8$ ways to pair them up.

---

Combining everything we have
$$9 \cdot (2 \cdot (1 \cdot 6 + 6 \cdot 6) + 6 \cdot (4 \cdot 6 + 3 \cdot 8))
= 3348.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different way of summarizing the casework. Call the people in the first group A, B, and C.

- Case 1: the partners of A, B and C are all in different groups. There are $9\cdot 6\cdot 3$ ways to choose the partners for A, B and C. Call the two un-chosen people in the second group D and E. There are four choices for D's partner, then two choices for E's partner (as D and E's partners cannot be in the same group). This means there are $9\cdot 6\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 2$ arrangements in this case.
- Case 2: All of A, B and C's partners are in the same group. There are $3$ choices for the group that $\{A,B,C\}$ is paired with, $3!=6$ ways to pair them up, then $3!=6$ ways to pair up the other groups.
- Case 3: Two of $\{A,B,C\}$'s partners are in the same group, and the other is in a different group. There are...

  - $\binom32=3$ ways to choose the two of $\{A,B,C\}$ whose partners are in the same group. WLOG they are A and B.
  - $9\cdot 2$ ways to choose the partners of A and B.
  - $6$ ways to choose the partner of $C$.
  - There is one group none of whose members have partners, call them $\{D,E,F\}$. There are $3!$ ways to assign partners to $\{D,E,F\}$.

Result:

$$9\cdot 6\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 2+3\cdot 6\cdot 6+3\cdot 9\cdot 2\cdot 6\cdot 6=3,348$$